# How to share the scope shared between extended namespaces?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, namespaces

Please take a look at the following code. First, a namespace holding a class is created. Then, the namespace is extended and the class we defined before is used. Here is a [live demo](http://ideone.com/QP65O1).

```
// File one
namespace system {
    class module {
        // ...
    };
}

// File two including file one
namespace system {
    struct entry {
        entry(module *module);
        module *module;
    };
}
```

Compiling this under gcc 4.8.1 without the permissive flag produces two compiler errors. Explicitly mentioning the namespace like `system::module` solves the problem, even though it is the same namespace we're already in.

```
error: declaration of ‘system::module* system::entry::module’ [-fpermissive]
    module *module;
            ^
error: changes meaning of ‘module’ from ‘class system::module’ [-fpermissive]
   class module {
         ^
```

Why is this code not standard conform? What other options do I have except explicitly mentioning the namespace every time.

Comment: Are you sure you want to name the variable the same as its class name?

Comment: @jxh Yes, I'd like to since this is a very abstract part of my application where I cannot really come up with more descriptive names. However, I could prefix the variable like `_module`. Would you give me the advice to do so?

Comment: Probably either postfix `_`, or use `m_` prefix would be more standard. You want to distinguish variable names from type names in some way to make your code easier to read. Perhaps capitalize your type name.

Comment: @jxh I decided against title case class names to stick with the underscore case conventions of the standard library. Postfixing the member with an underscore sounds reasonable. However, what can I do to distinguish local variables, types and namespaces? It seems to over complicate things. Maybe there is a gcc flag that allows just this behavior but not everything that is implies by `-fpermissive`.

Comment: I think you need to ask yourself why you want to write code that will be confusing for someone else to read.

Comment: @jxh To be honest, I don't think that this is harder to read. Everyone has syntax highlighting these days so types and variables are easy to distinguish, without the need for a second words to keep in mind. For namespaces, it's just a lack of convention. Do you know of any convention how to name them?

Comment: `int module = sizeof(module);` what is the syntax highlighter going to do with that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61130/discussion-between-danijar-and-jxh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in another answer, the compiler is complaining that you have changed the semantics of an identifier from a type to a variable name (`module`).

You should give your types a name that will make them easily distinguishable from variables. You should give member variables names that can be easily distinguished from regular variables. This increases code readability and maintainability. And, it has the side-effect of making the problem you face a non-issue:

```
// File one
namespace system {
    class module_type {
        // ...
    };
}

// File two including file one
namespace system {
    struct entry {
        entry(module_type *module);
        module_type *module_;
    };
}
```

Comment: You ask about how the standard library deals with this. That is implementation specific, each vendor will do things differently. If you look at the GNU version of the libstdc++, you will definitely see them wrap the standard type names over their implementations. And their implementations use a coding convention that lets them distinguish type names from variable names, and member variables from regular variables.

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
module *module;
```

you redefined name module.

So in the member function declaration you have to use elaborated type name

```
entry( class module *module);
```

In any case it is a bad idea to redefine names such a way.

Comment: Currently, I use the same name for class and instance and sometimes even for the namespace that wraps the class. Since I'd like to stick with underscore case, how does the standard library solve this? It feels silly to spell out the semantics like `namespace namespace_module`.

Comment: @danijar You may name a namespace and a class with the same name. However when you name an object with the same name as a class then the object name hides the name of the class and you have to use elaborated type name for the class (or enumeration).

Answer (score 1):

```
// File one
namespace system {
    class module {
        // ...
    };
}

// File two including file one
namespace system {
    struct entry {
        entry(module *module);
        module *module;
    };
}
```

> where I cannot really come up with more descriptive names

Naming is one of the most difficult challenges programmer's face, and yet, when shown a way (or 2 or n), it will forever be easier.

I offer the following - from a Coding standard I have long used.

```
class and namespace names are Capitalized, at least the 1st char

variable names are lower case (or camel case with lower case 1st char)


// File one
namespace System {
    class Module {
        // ...
    };
}

// File two including file one
namespace System {
    struct Entry {
        Entry(Module* module);
        Module* module;
    };
}
```

So?

Search for and read some of the coding standards.  They exist for a reason. Once you learn one good idea, it will serve the rest of your career.

Comment: Previously I was using title case names, too. However, now I'd like to stick with the standard library conventions. So everything is lower case. Do you know how the standard library approaches this?

Comment: @danijar - There was a time when vendor provided libraries used double-underscore (postfix or prefix) to keep their symbols unique, and stop interference with user symbols.  Of course, this only encouraged some users to use double underscore, because they were only following the vendors choice.    In other words, IMHO, standard library conventions are for standard libraries, not for your personal libraries.  Check with your QA dept, team lead, or professor.   Good luck.  Oh, and no, I do not know how other's approach this issue ...